# JSON AnyObject to Bool cast always returns nil

Tags: ios, swift

```
if let service = dict["service"] as? [String: AnyObject] {//dict is JSON object
        if let boolValue = service["isDeliverable"] {//Value is: false
            let isTrueVal = boolValue as! Bool // Crash as Bool is not a type of AnyObject
            let isTrueVal =  boolValue as? Bool // Always returns nil
        }
    }
```

How to cast AnyObject of type Bool of swift?

Comment: Use the debugger. What type is shown for `boolValue`?

Comment: @rmaddy :I mentioned already. It is AnyObject...I tried all the way of converting to bool... If that value is in numeric can be cast to NSNumber N then bool... But here the value gets as true/false

Comment: You can use `NSNumber` as well for `Bool`.

Comment: @OOPer but the value is kind of chars(true/false) ...

Comment: Have you actually tried? `let isTrueVal = (boolValue as! NSNumber) as Bool`

Comment: @OOPer yes ... As! NSNumber fatal error wrapping nil vale kind of

Comment: I cannot reproduce the same issue. When using `CFBoolean` succeeds, just replacing to `NSNumber` also succeeds.

Comment: @OOPer : Im not sure how u R defining the dictionary... As of now I'm getting from the server and it's a json object

Comment: I'm assuming you are using `JSONSerialization`.

Answer (score 1):

[As I found that using `CFBoolean`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/1667097-cfboolean) can achieve this :

> CFBoolean objects are used to wrap boolean values for use in Core
>   Foundation property lists and collection types.

```
if let service = dict["service"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
        if let boolValue = service["isDeliverable"] {
            let isTrueVal = (boolValue as! CFBoolean) as Bool 
        }
    }
```